# data.table merge on duplicate column name / how to write J corresponding to names in Y?

Tags: r, data.table

I have some troubles using data.table for a "double" merge. Here is what I'd like to do in plain english. I have some graph/network data (i.e., nodes and edges) and I would like to merge some node attributes into my data.table containing the edges. How can I merge the additional information from the "node" data.table into the "edge" data.table twice (once for the "From" and once for the "To" column)? The first merge works easy, but in the second merge, I cannot seem to figure out how to get the newly merged columns into my return DT (i.e., writing the right *j* statement. Here is some sample data to illustrate:

```
set.seed(1)
nodes <- data.table( NodeID=c("N1", "N2", "N3", "N4", "N5"), 
                     Name=c("Alice", "Bob", "Charlie", "David", "Emily"), 
                     key="NodeID")

edges <- data.table( EdgeID=1:10, 
                     From=sample(nodes$NodeID, 10, replace=TRUE), 
                     To=sample(nodes$NodeID, 10, replace=TRUE))
setkey(edges, From, To)
```

My desired output is to have a new data.table that adds the "Name" column from the nodes data.table to the edges data.table TWICE: once for the "From" column and once for the "To" column.

```
   From EdgeID To    FromName ToName
1:   N1     10 N4    Alice    David
2:   N2      2 N1    Bob      Alice
3:   N2      1 N2    Bob      Bob
4:   N2      5 N4    Bob      David
5:   N3      3 N4    Charlie  David
6:   N4      9 N2    David    Bob
...
```

The first merge (for the "From" column) is easy:
    edges[nodes]
The second one is harder since it needs a separate *by* argument (for the "To" column). But specifying a *by* argument forces you to also specify *j*. But how can I reference to the *new* column which would be created only after the merge is complete?

```
edges[nodes, ????, To]
```

Maybe I'm completely off track here and there is a much better way of doing it.

Comment: This isn't data.table but if you convert the nodes and edges to data frames `edges_df <- as.data.frame(edges); nodes_df <- as.data.frame(nodes)` then SQL supports multi-way joins and can be used like this`:  `library(sqldf); sqldf("select e.*, n1.Name as FromName, n2.Name as ToName  from edges_df e, nodes_df n1, nodes_df n2 on e.'From' = n1.NodeID and e.'To' = n2.NodeID")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would set the key of `edges` twice, and join twice.

```
setkey(edges, From)
edges[nodes, FromName := Name]
setkey(edges, To)
edges[nodes, ToName := Name]

## one-liner
setkey(setkey(edges, From)[nodes, FromName := Name], To)[nodes, ToName := Name]
```

Comment: I personally prefer the multi-liner. Easier to see what you've done. +1

Comment: +1 I knew I was missing something very basic about data.table.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are trying to do something like the following:

```
library(reshape2)
packageVersion("data.table")
# [1] ‘1.8.11’
x <- melt(edges, id.vars="EdgeID")
setkey(x, "value")
setkey(nodes, "NodeID")
dcast.data.table(nodes[x], EdgeID ~ variable, value.var="Name")
#     EdgeID    From      To
#  1:      1     Bob     Bob
#  2:      2     Bob   Alice
#  3:      3 Charlie   David
#  4:      4   Emily     Bob
#  5:      5     Bob   David
#  6:      6   Emily Charlie
#  7:      7   Emily   David
#  8:      8   David   Emily
#  9:      9   David     Bob
# 10:     10   Alice   David
```

The basic idea is to convert the "edges" `data.table` into a "long" dataset before merging, and then reshape the output back into a "wide" form after merging.

---

> **NOTE**: To use `dcast.data.table`, you need a more recent version of "data.table" (at least version 1.8.11). To install the latest development version, install it with:
>
> ```
>    install.packages("data.table", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")
> ```

---

You can also merge again with "edges" if you want the original "From" and "To" columns to be there in the output:

```
dcast.data.table(nodes[x], EdgeID ~ variable, value.var="Name")[edges]
#     EdgeID    From      To From.1 To.1
#  1:      1     Bob     Bob     N2   N2
#  2:      2     Bob   Alice     N2   N1
#  3:      3 Charlie   David     N3   N4
#  ///SNIP///
#  9:      9   David     Bob     N4   N2
# 10:     10   Alice   David     N1   N4
```